# Reduce image size while uploading

Tags: java, php, javascript

Is it possible to reduce image size while uploading ?

Can the size be Reduce from 2MB to 500kb or less or something like that
while uploading file?

Comment: What types of images are you talking about (PNG, JPG, BMP, something else)? And which language are you interested in? You've tagged your question with 3 different possibilities...

Comment: If you're using Java, there's certainly libraries to help you reduce the size of an image before you upload.  If you're using PHP, there are several (Imagick, GD, Exactimage, etc.) that can help you after the upload is complete.  You can't do it *during* the upload though.

Comment: is it possible with any language .. i prefer php and while upload to server ... so that low size image goes to server taking less server space ... thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it works fine. I use this class in PHP:

```
<?php

    function thumbnail( $img, $source, $dest, $maxw, $maxh ) {      
        $jpg = $source.$img;

        if( $jpg ) {
            list( $width, $height  ) = getimagesize( $jpg ); //$type will return the type of the image
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $jpg );

            if( $maxw >= $width && $maxh >= $height ) {
                $ratio = 1;
            }elseif( $width > $height ) {
                $ratio = $maxw / $width;
            }else {
                $ratio = $maxh / $height;
            }

            $thumb_width = round( $width * $ratio ); //get the smaller value from cal # floor()
            $thumb_height = round( $height * $ratio );

            $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );
            imagecopyresampled( $thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height );

            $path = $dest.$img."_thumb.jpg";
            imagejpeg( $thumb, $path, 75 );
        }
        imagedestroy( $thumb );
        imagedestroy( $source );
    }

?>
```

`imagejpeg( $thumb, $path, 75 );` is where how much you want the size and quality of the image after uploading.

Calling in PHP script:

```
if( isset( $_FILES['img-content'] ) ) {
    $img = str_replace( " ","_",$_FILES['img-content']['name'] );
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['img-content']['tmp_name'], "../../images/content/".$img );
    $source = "../../images/content/";
    $dest = "../../images/thumb/";
    thumbnail( $img, $source, $dest, 480, 400 );
```

}

Comment: thx but this will reduce the side after upload ... and size will be reduce for output but on server there will be a big file of 4 mb or 2 mb ... can we reduce  the size while upload ? ... so i can take of upload restriction for user from 500 kb per image and let them upload any size and script will reduce the size??

Comment: How about deleting the old image after uploading and keep the thumbnail one? Hope it fits your need

Comment: thx for help ... but i want user to upload there profile photos ... so i cant delete all images .... thx

Comment: any way i will try this script ... can u please explain $img, $source, $dest, $maxw, $maxh  ... as far as i understand $img(?), $source(is this source of image), newname, $maxwidth, $maxhight

Comment: Check the above answer, I passed the script to call this function. Hope you can figure out.